# Is it possible to setup ChallengeResponseAuthentication only for selected SSH users?

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to setup `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` only for selected SSH users?

I am using AWS AMI, and have setup MFA using `google-authenticator` package. It's working as expected.

My primary concern is that for any major failure (e.g. lost my phone) will lead to a total loss of the jumphost. I was thinking if I could create a plain vanilla user, set up keys etc. on another micro instance, and then stop that instance during ordinary times.

Will appreciate some helpful guidance. Are there other ways to accomplish the same objective?

--UPDATE--

See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/63129 for step by step instructions

For good measure, I also added an additional line to second sshd-config:

```
AllowUsers a-user-name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` can be set only globally and is not a valid option in a `Match` block, which can be used to change settings for different user.

The only alternative I can think of is running a second `sshd` daemon on different port with different configuration file, which would accept only a single user (`AllowUsers` option).